# How to recover slice-curve $g$ from a multivariate probability distribution $F$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: probability, distributions, multivariate-analysis, measure-theory, multivariate-distribution

Let $P$ be a probability measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $F$ be the corresponding distribution function. Also let $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ be the 'default' density function of $F$ (i.e. the radon nicodym derivative w.r.t. the lebesgue measure).

Now let $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$ be two points in $\mathbb{R}^n$. So joining these two points gives us a straight line in $\mathbb{R}^n$ (which need not go through the origin). Intuitively it's clear that we can 'slice' the density function $f$ along the straight line and get a curve $g,$ supported on the straight line joining $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$.

My question is, given the functional form of $f$ and the two points $\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y} \in \mathbb{R}^n,$ how can I recover $g$?

The question is also posted here : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2533473/how-to-recover-slice-curve-g-from-a-multivariate-probability-distribution-f

Comment: Taken literally, the answer to your question seems trivial: any point on this line is parameterized naturally in the form $\mathbf{z}=t\mathbf{x}+(1-t)\mathbf{y}$ for $t\in\mathbb R$ and (therefore) $g$ is expressed in terms of $t$ as $g(t)=f(t\mathbf{x}+(1-t)\mathbf{y})$. Please edit your post, then, to clarify what $g$ is intended to represent and to indicate more precisely what you mean by "recover" it.